# Read GET parameters in APACHE Mod Rewrite rules for WordPress categories in Posts

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite, routing

I'm a self-taught programmer with a very little experience in WordPress programming. I'm using a post permalink structure in this way:

`https://domain.com/parent-category/child-category/post-title-here/`

I want to have the possibility to optionally have URLs with two "parameters", "routes", "deepth-levels" like this:

`https://domain.com/parent-category/child-category/post-title-here/john-doe/light-blue/`

With APACHE's mod_rewrite I know I can "convert" a URL like: `https://domain.com/index.php?name=john-doe&color=light-blue` in some like: `https://domain.com/john-doe/light-blue/`

But, in WordPress, how can I do this without messing all the other URLs and routing process-flow? My goal is read the GET params `name` and `color` in the `functions.php` file so I can make some code with that.

EDIT:

I think that a mod_rewrite rule for "converting" / accepting  URLs like this `https://domain.com/parent-category/child-category/post-title-here/?name=john&color=light-blue` in something like this `https://domain.com/parent-category/child-category/post-title-here/john-doe/light-blue/` would do the trick! Using [add_rewrite_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

Thanks for reading.